# Installing Rails on ubuntu

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I want to install Rails in my ubuntu  system.So I followed the document https://help.ubuntu.com/8.04/serverguide/C/ruby-on-rails.html.Where I did sudo apt-get install rails an d it installed rails.Now the next step is to Modify the /etc/apache2/sites-available/default configuration file to setup your domains.So can you tell me how to mpodify that?

Comment: i guess you should install rails as a gem, no?

Comment: Are you using Ubuntu 8.04? If not, there are really far better and up-to-date guides out there

Answer (score 1):

Try

```
gksudo gedit /etc/apache2/sites-available/default&
```

It should ask for your password and open the file for modification.

Answer (score 0):

You'll need to run a text editor on the configuration file. Something like:

```
sudo gedit /etc/apache2/sites-available/default
```

Or replace gedit with your favourite editor such as nano, vim, emacs, etc...

Answer (score 0):

You can find everything you need here :

https://help.ubuntu.com/community/RubyOnRails

Apache is here :

https://help.ubuntu.com/community/RubyOnRails#Configure%20Apache

Answer (score 0):

I've tried to provide a good guide for getting Rails up and going on Ubuntu 11.04 (but it should be backwards compatible as well): http://blog.dcxn.com/2011/06/21/rolling-with-rails-3-on-ubuntu-11-04/

The gist of it is:

1. Install RVM
2. Install Rails from Gem
3. Rock out and write that great web app!

Hope it helps